# Deploying rails docker on ec2 and redirecting traffic from 80 to 4000

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, port, aws-security-group

I have a dockerized rails app that I am trying to deploy to aws ec2. I managed to make it run in docker on ec2 and map port 4000, docker_compose.yml :

```
  app:
    image: davidgeismar/artifacts-app:latest
    command: 'rails server -p 4000'
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    volumes:
      - ./log/production.log:/artifacts_data_api/log/production.log
```

On the aws dashboard in security groups I allowed http traffic from any source :

```
HTTP    TCP 80  0.0.0.0/0
```

I wanted to open port 3000 but it is not possible on aws dashboard. From what I understand I am now supposed to redirect traffic from port 80 to port 3000. I followed those instructions to do that : https://serverfault.com/questions/320614/how-to-forward-port-80-to-another-port-on-the-samemachine

Now when I try to access my application server through my brower using `ipv4:public_instance_ip/80` or `ipv4:public_instance_ip:80`I always get :

```
This site can’t be reached
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Could you provide guidance on how to achieve this ?

Comment: If you forwarded from port 80 to port 3000 you can't access your container which is running on port 4000.  Try changing your port mapping to 80:4000 the first number is the port on the host machine, the second is the port in the container you want to map it to.  Also remove the port forward as it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: changing the port mapping to 80:4000 worked !